# Sending Keys to test Tab index and close tabs in Behat (MacOSX, Behat, Chromedriver, Selenium2)

Tags: php, jquery, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver, behat

1) Is there a way to send a Tab key through to the browser to test the tab index of a page?

2) Is there a way to send a W key through to the browser while also simulating the holding down of the cmd key to close a tab in chrome?

We have tried using the keyPress() function, and have also used the following function with jQuery:

```
/**
 * @Given /^(?:|I )manually press "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function manuallyPress($key)
{
    $script = "jQuery.event.trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : '" . $key . "' });";
    $this->getSession()->evaluateScript($script);
}
```

Neither of them will behave as expected (they do not seem to be working at all).

Has anyone got a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've spent a fair bit of time on this issue and here are my results:

1. Behat does not have a pre-defined step to just send keys to any element on the page. It does have `pressKey` method (`@Given I press the :char key in the :field field`), but it works only with field as a target of the key event. **You would have to write your own `pressKey` to send keys to a custom CSS element**
2. Behat uses Selenium, which in its turn uses JS `Syn` library to symulate synthetic browser events. This library is injected into the page by Selenium.
3. Selenium uses `Syn.trigger('keydown',...)` to send characters  to elements, but it does not seem to work as expected. Instead, using `Syn.key(DOMElement, 'tab')` would actually send the `tab` key to the  `DOMElement` element. **You would have to implement this as well to make your `pressKey` work as expected.**
4. Behat is written using Symfony components and uses `DriverFactory` class to create drivers, including selenium driver. For some reason, the `Selenium2Driver` class is hardcoded, so there is no way to inject your own extended implementation of this class. **You would have to use reflection to piggy-back on exiting protected methods of `Selenium2Driver` class to include `Syn` library and execute JS code from previous step.**
5. There is a special case for tab key triggered in window without target element focused - this is the case when you want to test something like `Skip to content` accessibility link. Such link should appear on first `Tab` character press, but `Syn`can tab only from another element that can receive focus.

   A working solution is to inject such element as a very first element after opening `<body>` tag. This element would be visually hidden, but compatible with screen readers. Then we trigger key on this element to make sure that an element that supposed to get the very first focus from tab index actually gets it. Note that injecting element and triggering key press on it does not make it focused itself.

The good news is that it is all doable and is working for me. The bad news is that, unfortunately, I cannot share the code (well, at least not this version and not just yet) :(